# bot builder sdk nodejs builder.Prompts.choice issue

Tags: node.js, botframework, prompt

When I am using choice options greater than 10, builder.Prompts.choice() does not render buttons. Please find the code below:

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Planet names', 'Mercury|Venus|Earth|Mars|Vesta|Juno|Ceres|Pallas|Jupiter|Saturn|Uranus');
```

But it doesn't display buttons in this case, since the options are more than 10. The options are getting rendered as below:

```
1. Mercury
2. Venus
3. Earth
4. Mars
```

Is there any other way to display more than 10 options as buttons ?

Thanks

Comment: What's your required channel?

Answer (score 0):

Add { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button } to end of the line

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Planet names', 'Mercury|Venus|Earth|Mars|Vesta|Juno|Ceres|Pallas|Jupiter|Saturn|Uranus', { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
```

Reference: [azure bot service prompt types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

It works for more than 10 options.

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which bank?", "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
```

result

[image]

Comment: I tried this option as well, it works fine for options less than 10. For options more than 10 it doesn't work. Looks like a limitation of ms botframework.

Comment: It seems to be working for webchat version. It doesn't work with messenger.

Comment: Facebook has set limitation of 3 buttons. There is no limitation for quick reply. If possible try to send options in quick reply